# Jira REST API - How to POST a new member to a project role?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to use the REST Api to manage project roles in JIRA. I've been able to GET a list of the roles and "actors" and DELETE a role member. But I can't POST a new role member correctly. I keep getting a 400 or 405 error. I'm using HttpClient 4.3.2 and Jira 6.0.2. Here is my code:

```
// Set up ssl configuration as a user in JIRA instance

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://jira.install/rest/api/2/project/KEY/role/10000");

StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"group\":\"jira-users\" }");
input.setContentType("Application/json");
post.setEntity(input);

client.execute(post);
```

Has anyone been able to do a similar call successfully?

Comment: I've even tried a simple curl request and now I get an error message saying "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING tokent\n...."

Comment: Your original post has a syntax error around the StringEntity. Also worth using Chrome, Inspect Element and look at the Network tab when you add a member to a project role in the browser

Comment: Oh thanks, it was just a typo I missed when asking the question. But I think I found the answer, it requires a username and password to POST to project roles. I'll reply with a complete answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest api requires basic authorization for a POST to the group roles but it's not explicitly stated in the API documentation. So here's how I got it to work:

```
String auth = "username:password";
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US_ASCII")));
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity input;

try {
    input = new StringEntity("{\"group\":\"your-jira-group\"}");
    input.setContentType("Application/json");
    post.setEntity(input);
    post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Two things were messing me up...the "A" in Application/json needed to be capitalized and you needed to authorize the session. I chose basic authentication and used HttpClient after testing it with curl.